# How to select/subset multiple time series data frames in a list with same dates

Tags: r, dataframe, date, merge, time-series

I have a list of data frames in the following fashion:

```
> Year<- c(1984, 1999, 2002, 2005, 2010)
> Val <- c(2,1,4,5,4)
> df1 <- cbind.data.frame(Year, Val)
> df1
  Year Val
1 1984   2
2 1999   1
3 2002   4
4 2005   5
5 2010   4

> Year<- c(1934, 1989, 2012, 2015, 2000)
> Val <- c(1,5,3,2,1)
> df2 <- cbind.data.frame(Year, Val)
> df2
  Year Val
1 1934   1
2 1989   5
3 2012   3
4 2015   2
5 2000   1

> Year <- c(1984, 1999, 2002, 2005, 2010)
> Val <- c(5,7,8,3,4.5)
> df3 <- cbind.data.frame(Year, Val)
> df3
  Year Val
1 1984 5.0
2 1999 7.0
3 2002 8.0
4 2005 3.0
5 2010 4.5

> c <- list(df1, df2, df3)
> c
[[1]]
  Year Val
1 1984   2
2 1999   1
3 2002   4
4 2005   5
5 2010   4

[[2]]
  Year Val
1 1934   1
2 1989   5
3 2012   3
4 2015   2
5 2000   1

[[3]]
  Year Val
1 1984 5.0
2 1999 7.0
3 2002 8.0
4 2005 3.0
5 2010 4.5
```

For my assignment I would like to select data frames from the list `c`, with the same `Year` values. So, that in another list, say `d` I have all the data frames from list `c` which have the same years. How to approach this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `intersect` i.e, extract the 'Year' column from the `list`, get the intersecting 'Year' values, and then do a `subset` to get the rows having only that 'Year' values in each of the `list` elements by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
years <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(c, `[[`, 'Year'))
c1 <- lapply(c, subset, subset = Year %in% years)
```

Comment: Hi, I am not getting any values in c1.

Comment: @Sayantan4796 that implies that you don't have any common elements in all the list elements for year?

Comment: @Sayantan4796 the `> years
numeric(0)` is returning no values.  What is your expected output